# nix-shell cannot change locale warning

Tags: nix

While running `nix-shell` without a `shell.nix` file the following warning pops up:

```
$ nix-shell -p glibcLocales
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en_GB.UTF-8): No such file or directory

[nix-shell:~]$
```

If found a couple of posts which speak about setting the environment variable `LOCALE_ARCHIVE_2_27` to some path. How do I set such an environment variable automatically to the correct path? Would it help to use some `shell.nix` file?

Edit: My locales are set as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

If I remove `LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"` from `/etc/locale.conf`, then the warning does not show up, even if `LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" nix-shell -p glibcLocales` is used.

Using nix-2.3.6 on Fedora 32

$ nix-channel --list
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable

Comment: Howdy! Just to be sure I'm trying to reproduce on the right platform before taking a look at it -- is this NixOS, or Nix on a different platform? Which nixpkgs release/channel? (The Nix version is much less important than the channel, since that's where the `glibcLocales` definition is coming from).

Comment: Howdy @CharlesDuffy, I've updated my question. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: Yup, it's a solid place to start; unfortunately, none of the environments I have available are a close match (can't repro on NixOS 19.09 or 20.03, don't have Fedora readily at-hand). Could you also add the output from running `locale` to the question? (Are _all_ the relevant variables set to `en_GB.UTF-8`, or only a subset?)

Comment: I updated my question reflecting a strange thing regarding `/etc/locale.conf`.

Comment: Btw. `/etc/locale.conf` seems to be coming from systemd.

Answer (score 3):

You can populate $LOCALE_ARCHIVE_2_27 with valid path in `shell.nix` like this:

```
❯ cat shell.nix
with import <nixpkgs> {};
mkShell {
  LOCALE_ARCHIVE_2_27 = "${glibcLocales}/lib/locale/locale-archive";
  buildInputs = [
    hello
  ];
}
❯ nix-shell

[nix-shell:~]$ echo $LOCALE_ARCHIVE_2_27
/nix/store/r24xc904amrdwfrzyijxmylxnxmwacm9-glibc-locales-2.31/lib/locale/locale-archive
```

Or pass expression as an argument

```
❯ nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> { }; runCommand "dummy" { LOCALE_ARCHIVE_2_27 = "${glibcLocales}/lib/locale/locale-archive"; buildInputs = [ hello ]; } ""'

[nix-shell:~]$ echo $LOCALE_ARCHIVE_2_27
/nix/store/r24xc904amrdwfrzyijxmylxnxmwacm9-glibc-locales-2.31/lib/locale/locale-archive
```

More details here https://gist.github.com/peti/2c818d6cb49b0b0f2fd7c300f8386bc3